# C++11 thread_local destructor control

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there some way to have more control over how thread_local objects are destroyed upon thread exit?  When using the old posix pthread_key_create for TLS storage, one was able to specify a destructor callback and do whatever you want.  I cant seem to find the equivalent for the new c++11 thread_local.
My issue is that I need to potentially delay destruction of the thread local data, as is may be pending use in another thread.  I would be able to do this using pthread_key_create.
After some extensive googling I did find __cxa_thread_atexit as a potential answer here, but couldn't find any good documentation on it and its unclear how to actually use it

Comment: If the data is used in another thread, then it's not really *thread local*, is it? Perhaps you should consider [shared pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)?

Comment: its basically a pool allocator which is thread local to the allocating thread, but the data is consumed/freed in another thread.